# Create and attach pdf in email with jquery

Tags: jquery, email, attachment, frontend, jspdf

I have a page in my website and I want to add a button like "Mail me" which will create a pdf file with the content of the page and it will attach this file to the mail. 
So if possible I want to avoid save the file locally, but instead just attach it to the mail.
I am using jsPDF in order to create a pdf from the html page, and it works fine.

Is it possible to attach this file now in the mail with javascript or jQuery, like only in front end or I have to send it with Ajax for example to the back end?

Thanksattach pdf in email jquery

Comment: You have to use Ajax.

Comment: you mean Ajax and then back end? So no Front end solution?

Comment: Are you sure what is Ajax, Frontend/Backend? When you make an Ajax  call you communicate to a server which is your backend service.

Comment: yes I know, and that is what I meant. that I need to make an ajax call in order to communicate with the backend server. So I cannot attach the file without sending it to back end. Like with the mailto in html for example?

Comment: No. Don't do a mail to. That's a huge security risk

Comment: ok thanks. I will try to do Ajax solution

Answer (score 0):

Use the Email Composer Plugin :)

https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/705